# Replacing variables with values in a DisplayFormula

Tags: differential-equations

Something I cannot figure out and can't find clear or similar answers to what I want to do:

I have created a **Styled Notebook** and in an **Inline Formula** cell have assigned some variables, for example `A=3`, `B=4`, `C=5`

Then in a **Display Formula** Cell I want to display a differential equation that uses the variables above. I just want to display it, not solve it. So wrote a differential equation in the Display Formula cell, and the output just gives me this and doesn't put the values of the variables.

$\frac{d^2y(t)}{dt^2}+(A-1)\frac{dy(t)}{dt}-By(t) = C\frac{dx(t)}{dt}+x(t) $

For the life of me I just can't figure out how to get it to replace `A`,`B`, and `C` with the value of the variable originally assigned.

I'll admit I've been trying to hack it. I'm sure if I start from ground zero and start to learn Mathematica I can figure it out eventually, but if someone can explain to me real quick what I'm doing wrong, or if this is possible, it would shed some serious light on my understanding.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Can you give a bit more details on the actual code you are using?

Comment: I selected File->New->Styled Notebook, then in an Input Cell I entered A=3, B=4, C=5.  Then I created a Display Formula Cell within the Styled Notebook and entered the differential equation above using.  So my question is, why can I not get the values of A,B, and C transferred to the equation I wrote?